# How do I solve the duplicate problem in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, duplicates

I have a company called A Holding (as MainCompany). There are B and C companies affiliated with this holding. I saved companies B and C to the system. I had chosen and saved the company they were affiliated with as A holding. When I list the companies, A Holding is saved again. However, A holding is registered as one in the database. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you stuck?

Comment: *When I list the companies, A Holding is saved again.* Could you please elaborate on this? How could a retrieval insert new record?

Comment: @PeterCsala First of all, thank you for your interest. I tried "input type = hidden" but it didn't work.

Comment: @PeterCsala I do not know how to explain this. Normally A holding company is on my list. When I save a new company affiliated to it, the company is saved. but  A Holding is also saved. Thus, there are two A holdings on my list. I should only have one A Holding.

Comment: Then please share with us the code of the `CompanyService`

Comment: @PeterCsala CompanyService/GetList function:

Comment: Please amend your post and include there the `CompanyService`'s source code.

Comment: @PeterCsala CompanyService/GetList function: CompanyModel company = new CompanyModel();
Company.ID = reader.GetInt32(0);

Company.MainCompanyID= reader.GetFieldValue<int>(reader.GetOrdinal(“main_companyid”));     like this.

Comment: As I said earlier please extend your question (by editing your post). Please include the **all relevant source code** unless we can't help you.

Comment: @PeterCsala Peter I think I found a solution. i will try it. thank you